# How to save user search results to db without adding too many records?

Tags: sql, database

The user enters some search criteria and there will be nearly 1000 results (mostly other users). I want to save these result for later use. I.e to show how many times a user has been shown on a search result and when and by whom etc..
So if I just save them normally and if there are 1000 search everyday there will be 1 million records added everyday. Which will mostly be similar , repeated data.

Can the db tables be designed in a way that I will have to, say, only add 2000 records intead of 1 million?

Comment: can't you make two tables.  one the query and an Id,  the second an Id, a foreign key called QueryId, the date, possibly the userid etc.  that way if you have multiples of the same query there is only one record in the query table.

Comment: if you want to show "how many times, when and by whom" then you will need to record every instance.  If you can get by with just "how many times" then a simple counter you update for every search would work.

Comment: @BryanDellinger the problem is with the results. each query will too many results and those results need be saved. Even in the case of just saving result id's that is still 1000 of integers saved per search

Comment: @Kurt that is what I was afraid of.. There needs to be date range. Like how many times in last month. maybe not exactly "by whom" but by which type of users.